# Best way to smooth scrolling long lists on the web page

Tags: javascript, html, performance-analysis, optimization

I'm looking for a free JavaScript library to display large data sets easily like for example Clusterize.js

Or an idea how this can be easily achieved?

It's about the best way to smooth scrolling long lists on the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [DataTables](https://datatables.net), it is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library. It is a highly flexible tool, based upon the foundations of progressive enhancement, and will add advanced interaction controls to any HTML table.

[Scroller](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/) is a virtual rendering plug-in for DataTables which allows large datasets to be drawn on screen very quickly. What the virtual rendering means is that only the visible portion of the table (and a bit to either side to make the scrolling smooth) is drawn, while the scrolling container gives the visual impression that the whole table is visible.